# Auto deployment java (daemon or web) application tool

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ubuntu, deployment

I want a tool that can do automatically deployment from local computer to remote Ubuntu server.
My projects are in java. They can be webapp or daemon app, or anything (but now only java); I have spring, hibernate, maven build in my projects.

Is there a tool that can help doing SSH login, run sql script, copy files, editing configuration (in a few .conf files) (mysql username, password, some url address,...), run the newly installed service, do version control, ...
Since deploment/patching packages manually is tedious and time consuming.
Or I have to write my own tool?

edited: We don't want (too many) developers to know server configuration information (since it's unsafe), deployment is done by only one (or a few) sysad. 
**I thought about Puppet and Chef. Do you think these two systems can help my situation.**

All suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggesst to use Maven for that. You can specify a plugin for each of the tasks and bind the plugins to a certaains build phase.

- For SSH upload use maven-deploy-plugin
- To run the script use sql-maven-plugin
- Copy files may be done with resource or assembly plugin. That depends on your needs
- The easisest way to edit conf file is to replace it. But if it's not an option, then use maven-replacer-plugin to replace entries in a config file by regexp

Answer (score 0):

Check out [kwatee](http://www.kwatee.net) (I am the creator). It's easy to configure via a web administration interface but deployment operations can then be fully automated using CLI tools, or an ant or maven plugin.